# Is there any possibility to insert my own javascript code into any website?

Tags: javascript

Imagine a website - for example YouTube. In every video I'd like to insert a link next to the title that will point to my website, and if I click it, it grabs the url and sends it to my site's database.

I've seen somewhere such a possibility (I don't remember where), consisted of the fact that you dragged a *.js file onto your browser window and it worked locally just for you in the browser like an extension to existing site or sth.

Can you point me to articles or other resources if this is possible?

Comment: Yes, either with an extension (using a content script) or using a user script. Alternatively, bookrmarklets and snippets (chrome only) work too.

Comment: Use TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey

Comment: You seem to be talking about Greasemonkey scripts, if you're talking about something that happens automatically whenever you visit certain sites after installing something, or bookmarklets, if you're talking about something that you trigger manually every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. You can use a browser extension such as [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox, or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Chrome.
2. Write a [Bookmarklet](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/).

Comment: **+1** My comment has been recognized, little did I know it could've been an answer (also for mentioning **Bookmarklets.**  (Not a famous quote) -  *My life is a lie.*